# Removing Duplicates in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a dictionary like so,

```
Dictionary<int, string> roadNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();

roadNames.Add(1, "Rosedale Rd");
roadNames.Add(2, "Transmere Rd");
roadNames.Add(3, "Rosedale Rd");
roadNames.Add(4, "Rosedale Rd");
roadNames.Add(5, "Rosedale Rd");
roadNames.Add(6, "Rosedale Rd");
roadNames.Add(7, "Rosedale Rd");
roadNames.Add(8, "Brown Rd");
roadNames.Add(9, "Harold Rd");
```

Is there a LINQ solution to remove the duplicates that are NEXT to each other. The result I am after is a list containing this,

```
Rosedale Rd
Transmere Rd
Rosedale Rd
Brown Rd
Harold Rd
```

Note that Rosedale Rd is still in the list twice. The idea is to remove duplicates that are next to each other, and in this case we are removing item 4, 5, 6, and 7.

Items 1 is not next to item 3, so it isn't removed.

UPDATE:

Don't worry about Dictionary not being ordered. Solutions for a list that is in order would be fine. I can handle the ordering. i.e.

```
List<string> roadNames = new List<string>()
{
    "Rosedale Rd",
    "Transmere Rd",
    // etc
};
```

Comment: You can't.  Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this using LINQ (other than `Aggregate()` hacking)

Comment: i was also looking at something similar to Aggregate, or MoreLinq.Batch

Comment: Is there a reason you want a LINQ solution?  It seems that a pure LINQ solution will be difficult, confusing and possibly slower than a solution not constrained to LINQ.

Comment: Just elegance. Open to all solutions if LINQ is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a sorted dictionary instead (or any other sorted structure), there are two options.

**Leverage Reactive Extensions**

This is very simple if you leverage [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) from Microsoft (which everyone should!):

```
roadNames.Values // remove if a list instead
         .ToObservable()
         .DistinctUntilChanged()
         .ToList();
```

You can change that final `ToList()` to to `ToEnumerable()` instead if you like.

This returns:

```
Rosedale Rd 
Transmere Rd 
Rosedale Rd 
Brown Rd 
Harold Rd
```

**Use an Extension Method**

You can use a `GroupAdjacent` extension method as such:

```
roadNames.Values // remove if a list instead
         .GroupAdjacent((x,y) => x == y)
         .Select(x => x.First());
```

The extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> adjacent)
{
    var g = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (g.Count != 0 && !adjacent(g.Last(), x))
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<T>();
        }
        g.Add(x);
    }
    yield return g;
}
```

Comment: I used the extension method which worked great. Wasn't really wanting to use reactive extensions.

Comment: @peter - Why has this been marked as the solution as neither of these options gives you what you asked for in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that uses the standard built-in LINQ operators:

```
var result =
    roadNames
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .Aggregate(
            new List<string>(),
            (xs, x) =>
            {
                if (xs.LastOrDefault() != x)
                {
                    xs.Add(x);
                }
                return xs;
            });
```

I've assumed that you want to order by key before selecting the value from the dictionary.