# Get duplicate values from dictionary

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have dictionary and I need get duplicate values.

For example:

```
 Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
                List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "John", "Smith" };
                List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "John", "Smith" };
                List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "Mike", "Johnson" };

                dictionary.Add(1, list1);
                dictionary.Add(2, list2);
                dictionary.Add(3, list3);
```

I need find all duplicate from dictionary and return max keys(collection of key) of each duplicate values. From my test dictionary I need return list with only one key = 2

Maybe I chose the wrong data structure. I would like to receive optimal algorithm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Duplicates in Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629393/removing-duplicates-in-dictionary)

Comment: What happens if you have John Robert Smith in one of your lists?  Would that be considered a duplicate as well?  Your current structure doesn't limit you to two strings per value

Comment: Would you please share your code how you currently find duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current structure, you're in a bit of trouble because you don't necessarily have an easy way to compare two `List<string>` to see if they are equal.

One way to work around this is to create a custom `List<string>` comparer that implements `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>`.  However, since you have a list of strings, we also need to reorder both to ensure that we are comparing each value in the correct order.  This affects the cost of your algorithm.  On the other hand, if you are happy with the order of the values inside of the lists, that works just fine as well and you can avoid that cost.

```
public class StringListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        return CompareLists(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    private static bool CompareLists(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;

        // we HAVE to ensure that lists are in same order
        // for a proper comparison
        x = x.OrderBy(v => v).ToList();
        y = y.OrderBy(v => v).ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < x.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Once we have our comparer, we can use it to pull out keys from subsequent duplicates, leaving the first key (per your requirement).

```
public List<int> GetDuplicateKeys(Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictionary)
{
    return dictionary
        .OrderBy (x => x.Key)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Value, new StringListComparer())
        .Where (x => x.Count () > 1)
        .Aggregate (
            new List<int>(),
            (destination, dict) => 
                {
                    var first = dict.FirstOrDefault();

                    foreach (var kvp in dict)
                    {
                        if (!kvp.Equals(first))
                            destination.Add(kvp.Key);
                    }

                    return destination;
                }   
        ).ToList();
}
```

The following test outputs keys 2 and 4.

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dictionary.Add(1, new List<string> { "John", "Smith" });
dictionary.Add(2, new List<string> { "John", "Smith" });
dictionary.Add(3, new List<string> { "Mike", "Johnson"});
dictionary.Add(4, new List<string> { "John", "Smith" });

var result = GetDuplicateKeys(dictionary);
```

Comment: You don't have to reorder the items. You can replace your comparison code with `return x.Count == y.Count && x.OrderBy(v => v).SequenceEqual(y.OrderBy(v => v));`

Comment: @JimMischel SequenceEqual is about half as fast.  In addition, you're making two calls to OrderBy which is no different.

Comment: I didn't say it was going to be faster. It's much more concise code, and arguably more clear, though. I retract the "You don't have to reorder the items." I had started to suggest building a `HashSet<string>` from each list and calling `SetEquals`. If speed is a consideration, I'd suggest creating a separate dictionary with ordered lists. That way you'd only have to sort each list once. That takes more memory, of course, but that's the typical tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of `KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>`, that contains the ordered lists, with the outer list sorted. Then you could find duplicates very quickly. You'd need a list comparer that can compare ordered lists.

```
class MyListComparer: Comparer<List<string>>
{
    public override int Compare(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        for (var ix = 0; ix < x.Count && ix < y.Count; ++ix)
        {
            var rslt = x[ix].CompareTo(y[ix]);
            if (rslt != 0)
            {
                return rslt;
            }
        }
        // exhausted one of the lists.
        // Compare the lengths.
        return x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);
    }
}

var comparer = new MyListComparer();
var sortedList = dictionary.Select(kvp => 
    new KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.OrderBy(v => v))
  .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value, comparer)
  .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

Note the `ThenBy`, which ensures that if two lists are equal, the one with the smaller key will appear first. This is necessary because, although `OrderBy` does a stable sort, there's no guarantee that enumerating the dictionary returned items in order by key.

```
// the lists are now sorted by value. So `"Smith, John"` will appear before `"Smith, William"`.
// We can go through the list sequentially to output duplicates.
var previousList = new List<string>();
foreach (var kvp in sortedList)
{
    if (kvp.Value.SequenceEqual(previousList))
    {
        // this list is a duplicate
        // Lookup the list using the key.
        var dup = dictionary[kvp.Key];
        // Do whatever you need to do with the dup
    }
    else
    {
        previousList = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

This sorts each list only once. It does use more memory, because it duplicates the dictionary in that list of `KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>`, but for larger data sets it should be much faster than sorting each list multiple times and comparing it against every other list.

Caveats: The code above assumes that none of the lists are `null`, and none of them are empty. If a list in the dictionary can be `null` or empty, then you'll have to add some special case code. But the general approach would be the same.